# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSignIn' when using services.AddSignIn(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C") from template

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, razor-pages, microsoft-identity-platform

I ran the templates from [AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki#asp-net-core-web-api-template) for Razor Pages:

```
dotnet new webapp2 --auth IndividualB2C
```

Which created a project using

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignIn(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
        services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }
```

But I looked into the .csproj file and saw:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="0.1.2-preview"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="0.1.2-preview"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

So I upgraded them as it looks like the new version for [Microsoft.Identity.Web was GA'd at 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web/). Now the line:

```
services.AddSignIn(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

Has this error:

'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSignIn' and no accessible extension method 'AddSignIn' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `services.AddSignIn()` is available in the nuget package of `Microsoft.Identity.Web` up to version `0.1.5 Preview` version, the above versions don't contain the `services.AddSignIn()`.

Please go through the [release notes](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/releases) of `Microsoft.Identity.Web`.

With the Current version 1.1.0 you can replace `services.AddSignIn()` with `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication()`

Comment: Thanks. The template seems to generate services.AddSignIn() so perhaps that needs to change as well.

Comment: Also the line `AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi` was changed to `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi`